# Outlook add code to button programmatically

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a user form which generates a number of command buttons, I need to then add code to these buttons programmatically.

I have tried using `.CodeModule.InsertLines` with no success. I have also tried `.OnClick` with no luck.

This needs to work in Outlook. Let me know if you need anymore info.

Answer (score 0):

Macro recorder helps you with learning these things.

```
Private Sub ButtonName_Click()
    'your code
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't what I need. I am already programmatically creating buttons onto a form and I want to add code to the button clicks. The code needs to be created dynamically along with the buttons.

Comment: This is VBA.  It's not the right tool for the job.  You should be more explicit in your question, and perhaps add code.

Comment: Outlook does not record macro